# Throw SEH exception with message

Tags: c++-cli, seh

I have a C++ library being called from a C# app using a C++/CLI wrapper library. In the C++ code I want to throw an exception when something goes wrong. It is translated into a SEHException in the managed world. However, the message the original exception contained naturally is gone.

How can I propagate this message through to C#?

- Can I somehow set up a translation so that e.g. `MyCppException` gets translated to `MyManagedException` marshaling the message?
- Can I somehow throw the exception is such a way that the SEHException contains a message?

I want to avoid having to catch my exception in all C++/CLI wrapper functions and rethrowing if possible.

```
// C++ cpp.h
class MyException { const char* what() const { return "OH HI THERE"; } };
MyException e;
void throw_function()
{
    throw e;
}

// Wrapper
#include "cpp.h"
public ref class A
{
public:
    static Throw() { throw_function(); }
}

public ref class E: public Exception
{
    System::String^ GetMessage();
}    

// App.cs
try
{
    A.Throw()
}
catch (E e)    
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetMessage()); // I would like to do something like this...
}
catch (SEHException seh)
{
    Console.WriteLine(seh.Message); // Or this...
}
```

Comment: You have to take care of his yourself.  Wrap the throw_function() call with try/catch and re-throw E.

Comment: As I suspected, luckily there aren't too many functions in the library.